# node executes asynchronously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, acl

In my express app I am implementing ACL using [node_acl](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl)

my acl.js looks like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
node_acl = require('acl'),
acl;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/aclExample', function _mongo_connected(){
    var mongoBackend = new node_acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db, 'acl_');
    acl = new node_acl(mongoBackend);

    
    console.log("ACL: ",acl);
});
set_roles();


function set_roles() {
    //set permissions for roles
    acl.allow([
        {
            roles: 'a',  //roles
            allows: [
                {resources: '/fe', permissions: ['put', 'delete']},
            ]   //permissions
        },
        {
            roles: 'b',
            allows: [
                {resources: '/fe/api', permissions: 'post'}
            ]
        },
        {
            roles: 'c',
            allows: [
                {resources: '/', permissions: ['post', 'put']}
            ]
        },
        {
            roles: 'd',
            allows: [
                {resources:'/fe', permissions: ['get', 'post']}
            ]
        }
    ]);
    acl.addUserRoles(420, 'b').then( ()=> console.log('added user'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
    acl.addUserRoles(520, 'a').then( ()=> console.log('added user'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
    //acl.isAllowed(userId, reso, pem);
  }

module.exports = acl;
```

and my app.js:

```
var acl = require('@root/fe-server/middlewares/fe.middleware.acl.js');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
console.log("ACL: ",acl);
```

The output I get looks like this:

```
ACL:  undefined
added user
added user
```

I can understand that node executes the console statement in app.js before the connection is established and db is created but I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said yourself, `mongoose.connect` takes some time and therefore it accepts a callback function to be executed once it's finished, which you have been using already.

Within that callback function you create the `acl` ressource and that means anything using the `acl` variable also has to be executed from within that callback (either directly or indirectly). So in your case you would have to do something like this:

**acl.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const node_acl = require('acl');

const connect = (callback) => {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/aclExample', (err) => {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    const mongoBackend = new node_acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db, 'acl_');
    const acl = new node_acl(mongoBackend);

    set_roles(acl).then(() => callback(null, acl)).catch(callback);
  });
};

const set_roles = (acl) => {
  acl.allow([ /* stuff */ ]);

  return Promise.all([
    acl.addUserRoles(420, 'b').then(() => console.log('added user b')),
    acl.addUserRoles(520, 'a').then(() => console.log('added user a')),
  ])
};

module.exports = connect;
```

**main.js**:

```
var connectACL = require('acl.js');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

connectACL((err, acl) => {
  console.log('ACL: ', acl);
});
```

The important change is that `require('acl.js')` now returns a function which accepts a callback, so that you can safely use `acl` after it has been created.

You can also see that `acl` uses a different kind of handling asynchronicity, which is called "Promises" (the `.then` and `.catch` stuff). Both are valid options but you'll usually want to decide to use one only and convert the other one as soon as possible (like I do here with `.then(() => callback(null, acl)).catch(callback)`).
However you will need one of those whenever you deal with asynchronous functions, as you have ensure that your code is executed in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you for the response. You're making a lot of sense but this didn't solve the problem. It still logs ACL as undefined in my console. You think async await could be the solution?

Comment: `async/await` is just a different syntax for working with Promises.
In my example I didn't include much error handling for simplicity, but it's quite possible that something within `connectACL` failed. In callback style, you'll get any possible errors as first callback parameter, for promises there is the `.catch` function.
I also just added a parameter to `set_roles` to fix a TypeError.

Comment: Even if this works, I still won't be able to access acl methods in my routes folder for authorization such as `acl.isAllowed()` or `acl.middleware()`. This was the reason I was exporting the acl variable from my acl.js file.

Comment: That is a very common problem and there are various solutions based what framework you are using. In `express` you can build a middleware that adds `req.acl = acl` which will make it accessible in any subsequent handler.

Or as a more advanced solution you can return a `getACL` function from `acl.js` which returns a Promise that resolves to `acl`. It's implementation can then make sure that the actual connection stuff is only done once and the results cached and returned on subsequent calls.